# Process status while page loading through label

Tags: c#, asp.net

Through my program i processing large no. of data,so i want to show status while processing the data 
E.g:-2 Records completed and so on

my code:-

asp.net:

```
<div class="loading" align="center">
    File Uploading. Please wait.<br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="LblStatus" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Cs page:

```
private void Process(int Rec)
{
    LblStatus.Text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < Rec; i++)
    {
        ProcessData(i);
        LblStatus.Text = i.ToString() + " Records completed";
    }
}
```

JS which I use for page loader

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowProgress() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var modal = $('<div />');
            modal.addClass("modal");
            $('body').append(modal);
            var loading = $(".loading");
            loading.show();
            var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
            loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
        }, 200);
    }
    $('form').live("submit", function () {
        ShowProgress();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your data get processing while page loading or in separate button actions?

Comment: separate button action

Comment: Okay, in `postback` or `ajax` request ?

Comment: postback,on button click loop will execute on each record i want to update counter of completed record

Comment: If your button click make `postback` action I think this is better to use prepared Javascript library to show real process loader indicator , such as [pace](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) it will control existence of element,document readyState,ajax and Event Lag.

Comment: I have tried it but it show percentage after execution complte  i want to show percentage of loop execution

Comment: But I am using this and shows real process bar, although your `loop` take a time and `pace` can control it.

Comment: Is any thing different i have to do to show progress bar according to looping method .

Comment: I have added space.js also added style

Comment: So this is better to send your request by JQuery `Ajax` or `UpdatePanel` in ASP.Net but If you would like to show progress exactly by loop steps I prefer to use `SignalR` to push notification to client in each step of loop.